# How to fix problem with Angular routing with refresh on Azure deploy

Tags: angular, azure, angular-routing

I am having an Angular(v7) project that I wanna deploy to Azure cloud. I am having a problem with routing. When I refresh page on one of my sub pages I get: ***"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."***

I look angular instruction  for deploying [a deployment instruction](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

I have also read a lot of post on that issue but I didn't find solution that would work for me.

My routing rule is very simple.

```
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'contracts',      component: ContractsComponent }
];
```

I have created web.config file in "Src" folder with content:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

also put in index.html

```
<base href='/'>
```

and it does not help. Is there any other thing that I could be check?

Comment: Have you tried including the wild card route at the end of your route definitions? Something like: `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}`?

Comment: I try it. It does not work.